# What's the logic behind approving an edit vs. making an edit on your own?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I mean right now I have +2000 reputation points, so I can edit whenever I want. Why isn't me approving an edit by another not weighed as the same?

If I'm someone who can make edits without waiting it to be approved, why aren't my approvals made effective immediately?